# Move buttons on a Dialog Box while it resizes

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, move

I have created a Dialog Box in a c++ windows application (using ATL lib) and I have set on it three buttons. The button lie as usual at the bottom of the Dialog Box. I want by the resize of the Dialog Box, the button to retain their position at the bottom of it. In other words, they should keep a constant (low) distance from the bottom margin and the on side (right or left) of the Dialog Box. To bring this into effect, I try to move the buttons accordingly while the Dialog Box size is changed. I use the following code (as example only with the OK button), but the only result is the button to disappear during the resize. How should I modify the code in order for the button to retain its distance from the bottom and the right side of the Dialog Box?

```
LRESULT RenameFolderDlg::OnSize(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(&r);

CWindow okB(GetDlgItem(IDOK));
RECT okR;
okB.GetWindowRect(&okR);

okB.MoveWindow( r.right - 80 , r.bottom - 40, okR.right - okR.left, okR.bottom -     okR.top, 1);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
GetWindowRect(&r);
```

you shall use

```
GetClientRect(&r);
```

because the coordinates returned by `GetWindowRect` are relative to the upper-left corner of the screen, while `MoveWindow` called for a child control expects they are relative to the upper-left corner of the parent window's client area.

Answer (score 4):

I use winapi. In that I use [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fetch cordinates of control and then use [MapWindowPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to map those rectangular coordinates on to screen. Then use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to position windows according to mapped rectangular coordinates.

On Google, I found [MapWindowPoints for ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsk6k6b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I think what you are legging in your code is mapwindowpoints. Try using that.

Hope it work....